# Redirect directory URL to instead have .html suffix

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

htaccess redirect (301) all my old content from my WordPress to my new URL design. I want to redirect all the last trailing slashes to .html  ... the permalinks are already working, but I don't want to lose all my collected backlinks for which I worked so hard.

This is how my URLs look like:

- Pages (old): `/pages/redirection/` should redirect to `/pages/redirection.html`
- Posts (old): `/new-permalink/` should redirect to `/news/new-permalink.html`
- Custom Posts `/permalink/` should redirect to `/projects/permalink.html`

The following rewrite rule does not work for me.  It ignores my rewritebase, so it redirects `/projects/permalink/` to `/permalink.html` not to `/projects/permalink.html`.

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteBase /project/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /project/index.php [L] 
RewriteRule /project/([^/]*)/?$ /project/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: If you are in `/projects/` folder already, then remove `/project/` from rewrite pattern for last rule; should be `RewriteRule ([^/]*)/?$ /project/$1.html [L]`. **P.S.** and please **stop** using xxxxx for everything -- be creative and use a bit more realistic/easy to distinguish URLs...

Comment: Ok, next time i try beeing more creative ;) ...now it returns on domain.com/project/  ...You don't have permission to access /project/.html on this server.

Comment: Which URL you were accessing? if `example.com/project/` .. then you may have such response. If so -- add `RewriteRule ^$ /project/index.php [L]` line after RewriteBase line, for example (but definitely before the previously mentioned rule).

Comment: doesnt work for me.. now it looks like this `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /project/ RewriteRule ^$ /project/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/?$ /project/$1.html [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: TBH Now I'm lost on what is working, what is not (and why) and how it **supposed** to work. Without knowing you project details I will constrain myself from making more "wild" guesses. I can only recommend enabling rewrite debugging (if you can edit server/virtual host config) -- `RewriteLogLevel 9` and check rewrite log for details. You are the person who knows for sure how site works/should work, and should see from logs what is going wrong and where. All my advices, while technically be correct, still may be inappropriate for particular situation/location.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)/?$ pages/$1.html
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: thx, but plz see my editted question :)